# Read file after open KB - Genexus extensions

Tags: events, load, genexus

I am creating a GeneXus extension and I want that on the AfterOpenKB event the extension reads a file. So, what I did was copy the files that I need read to the packages folder in GX. The thing is that when I am debugging the extension, the method AfterOpenKB is called twice and in one of those is searching for the file in the KB's folder.

The question is, it's expected that the method trigger twice or am I doing something wrong? Should I copy the file to the KB's folder too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AfterOpenKB event should be fired only once every time a process opens a KB. Is your extension a UI or a BL extension? I suspect you're developing a BL extension, and what you're seeing is that the MSBuild process for the specifier, which is an independent process and also starts the GX BL, triggers the AfterOpenKB event when opening the same KB as the GX process is opening.

Can't give an answer to if you should copy the files to the KB folder, without knowing exactly what the extension is doing, but in general, don't believe is a good practice to copy files to the GX installation when opening a KB. Note that it'll be fairly common that GX is located inside Program Files, and writing files into that path will require elevated privileges. Currently GX requires to run as an elevated process, but that's something we may like to change in the future, so I heavily suggest against depending on that. The KB folder seems a better place to copy the files, but again, can't tell for sure without knowing exactly what the extension is doing and what are the files for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is both,UI and BL extension, has UI(menu, windows tool) and creates objects in KB. The extension reads a XML file that contains information for creating folders, procedures, SDTs, etc. in the KB.

Comment: Is the content of the xml file generated dynamically? Or will it always be the same for a certain version of your extension? If the content is static, I'd put the file inside the GX installation when the extension is installed (not on every after KB opened event). For instance, inside a folder of your own, inside the Packages folder of the GX installation. This way, you only require admin privileges to install your extension, and not each time it runs.

Comment: Is not generated dynamically, may vary sometimes..like you said. I still have the problem that OnAfterKB event triggers twice...there is a way to control that behavior?
Thanks!